# inline() vs inline_outer() in Spark SQL, Built-in Functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I found [inline()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) and [inline_outer()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline_outer) in [Spark SQL, Built-in Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#built-in-functions).The official examples of these two functions are the same. I can't tell the difference between them. This is why I am really confused about which one I should choose. Can I use both of them in any case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L8036) i found this in comment:

> def inline_outer(col: "ColumnOrName") -> Column:
> """
> Explodes an array of structs into a table.
> Unlike inline, if the array is null or empty then null is produced for each nested column.

And test for this code:

```
def test_inline(self):
        from pyspark.sql.functions import inline, inline_outer

        d = [
            Row(structlist=[Row(b=1, c=2), Row(b=3, c=4)]),
            Row(structlist=[Row(b=None, c=5), None]),
            Row(structlist=[]),
        ]
        data = self.spark.createDataFrame(d)

        result = [tuple(x) for x in data.select(inline(data.structlist)).collect()]
        self.assertEqual(result, [(1, 2), (3, 4), (None, 5), (None, None)])

        result = [tuple(x) for x in data.select(inline_outer(data.structlist)).collect()]
        self.assertEqual(result, [(1, 2), (3, 4), (None, 5), (None, None), (None, None)])
```

As you can se inline_outer produced one extra row for empty entry